# mocha test passes even when assertion fail if async function wrapped with try catch

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, chai, supertest

Without the try catch blocks, the test fails normally when there is an assertion error

```
describe("POST /foo", function () {
  it('should create a foo', async function () {
      const response = await request.post("/foo").send(data);
      expect(response.status).to.eql(200); //Assertion error
  }).timeout(10000);
})
//+ expected - actual -500 + 200 1 failing
```

However, the test passes if I wrap it with try/catch block

```
describe("POST /foo", function () {
 it('should create a foo', async function () {  
    try {
       const response = await request.post("/foo").send(data);
        expect(response.status).to.eql(200); //Assertion error
      } catch (err) {
      }
    })
})
//1 passing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertion libraries (like [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/)) have functions like `expect` and `assert` that will throw exceptions when the condition they are checking for fails. A test runner (mocha in this case) can use this fact to detect test failures by executing the test case within a try/catch block. If an exception is thrown by the test case (i.e., by the assertion library), the test is deemed to have failed.

If you look at [mocha's documentation](https://mochajs.org/#assertions), for example, you will see that:

> Mocha allows you to use any assertion library you wish...generally,
> if it throws an Error, it will work!

So in pseudocode, mocha is doing something like:

```
function testRunner() {
  try {
    testCase('should create a foo'); // run a test case defined by the user
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('The test has failed');
    return;
  }
  console.log('The test has succeeded.');
}
```

If you wrap all of the code in your test case in a try/catch block, as in your second example, you are preventing mocha from seeing exceptions raised by the assertion library's `expect` statement. (The catch block you define is "swallowing" the exception). mocha, seeing no exception, assumes there was no problem, and the test is marked as passed.